# Question about iterating through array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array which is not necessarily full.

It can be very sparse.

Is there a good way to iterate through this array without visiting all the possible indexes? (c++ array iterator?)

Or, even if I use array iterator, will it be nothing different from visiting every indexes and checking the value?

Comment: Arrays are always "full", they are always a contiguous sequence of memory. There are no "holes" that you need to skip.

Comment: @Kerrek: no, but it have "logical" holes.  I consider NULL items in an array of pointers to be "holes".

Comment: How would you know which index to skip without looking at what is contained at the index?

Comment: Why not choosing a proper data structure instead of randomly using a structure and ask for a patch for the structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you use an iterator, it's the same as visiting every index and checking the value, and there's no good way to skip logical holes. You could keep a list of good indices, but if you did that then why not just use a list to store the data in the first place?

If your data is very sparse, perhaps a better data structure would be a `std::map`, or even an `std::unordered_map`, depending on your application. These have decent lookup time while not wasting much space, like an array would have to.

Comment: Just wondering... you said `std::map` will have decent look up time. Does that mean O(1) like array? or O(n) like queue?

Comment: @user482594 `O(lg n)` actually - between an array and queue, but closer to an array. For instance, if you had an array of 1 million elements, it would always take 1 unit of time to access any one. If you had a list or queue of 1 million elements, it could take 1 million units of time to access any one. But if you had a `map` of 1 million elements, the **most** it could take would be 19 units of time to access any one. So yeah, it's pretty bloody fast for not being an array. Note that `unordered_map`, because it's an hash table, will be faster usually (`O(1)` unless you have collisions).

Answer (score 1):

Associate Array is what you are trying to build. I suggest you look for a library that does this for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a key/value association that simulates an array, just use a std::map holding a std::pair. You can then retrieve your values with the index (key), and iterate quickly over only your set of actual values.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

std::map has syntax conveniences like operator[] that will act like an array.

Answer (score 0):

Should you really need to stick with your array based solution `boost::filter_iterator` could be useful. Here is small example with integer arrays:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iterator/filter_iterator.hpp>

struct is_not_null {
  bool operator()(int* t) {
    return t != NULL ? true : false;
  }
};

int main()
{
  int* a[] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
  a[0] = new int[3];
  a[0][0] = 1; a[0][1] = 2; a[0][2] = 3;
  a[3] = new int[3];
  a[3][0] = 3; a[3][1] = 4; a[3][2] = 5;
  a[5] = new int[3];
  a[5][0] = 5; a[5][1] = 6; a[5][2] = 7;

  typedef int** base_iterator;
  typedef boost::filter_iterator<is_not_null, base_iterator>
    FilterIter;

  for(FilterIter it = boost::make_filter_iterator< is_not_null >(a, a + 6);
      it != boost::make_filter_iterator< is_not_null >(a + 6, a + 6);
      ++it) {
    std::cout << (*it)[0] << " " << (*it)[1] << " " << (*it)[2] << std::endl;
  }

  // nevermind the leaks
  return 0;
}
```